# Console inputting a multiple digit number in assembly, using functions of int21h

Tags: function, assembly, x86-16, digit, emu8086

Okay, so I have a rather stupid question, I would say. I had to write a program that reads a number from the keyboard and decides whether it is prime or not. It seems to be working pretty well (here it is) but only for one-digit numbers. If I try to read, let's say, 10, it will only read 1. What could I possibly do so that I could read numbers with more than one digit? Thanks in advance and sorry for the possible

```
assume ds: data_, cs:text_
data_ SEGMENT
Message db 'Enter the number: $'
Message2 db 'Prime $'          
Message3 db 'Not prime $'              
number dw ?
aux db ?
nrd db 1
var db 2

data_ ENDS

text_ SEGMENT
start:
   mov ax, data_
   mov ds, ax
   mov es, ax

   mov cl, 2      ;cl will be used as an index for the divisors of the number which are different from 1 and the number itself
   add cl, 48     ;conversion to decimal

   mov ah, 09h
   mov dx, offset Message   ;we print the Message before reading the number
   int 21h

   mov ah, 08h
   int 21h                  ;using the 08h function, the number is read
   sub al, 30h              ;conversion to decimal
   mov ah, 0                ;conversion from byte to word
   mov number, ax           ;the read number is copied to the variable number
   div var                  ;since the number is required to be prime, it is enough to check the divisors up until its half, so we divide it by var (which has the value 2)
   add al, 48               ;conversion to decimal
   mov aux, al              ;the half is moved to aux so that al can be used without losing the value in it
   mov ax, number           ;we move the initial number back to ax


   et1:                     ;in et1, we check whether a number divides itself by the index or not ;if it does, a divisor is found
    cmp cl, aux                                       
    je et2               ;the set index is compare to the half of the number; if it's equal, we go to et2
    div cl                                            
    cmp ah, 0                                           
    je increment                                           
    inc cl                                              
    jmp et1                                            

   increment: 
    inc nrd              ;nrd is used to count the divisors of the number

   et2:                     ;if there are more than 1 divisor (which is 1), the number isn't prime and we jump to et 3 ;otherwise, we print Message2
    cmp nrd, 1
    jg et3
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset Message2
    int 21h
    jmp exit

   et3:                    ;if the number isn't prime, Message3 is printed
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset Message3
    int 21h     

  exit:
   mov ax, 4C00H
   int 21H  
   text_ ENDS
   end start
```

Comment: Obviously you will have to read more than 1 character, and you will need to write the conversion yourself. Plenty of examples around.

Comment: @Jester would be reading with 0Ah a good idea? Or should I stick to this one and simply loop it?

Comment: @Katrin using `0A` or single char doesn't make huge difference, the `0A` service includes some basic edit functionality, so you can use backspace to fix typo, etc... but for simple value input it may be enough to use char-in in a loop. (and you may even manually handle backspace code, although that may need to print to screen to delete the last char, which will get a fraction beyond beginner level, like do that after you have working initial simpler things). But `0A` vs `08` is no big deal, try even both (write one first, debug it until it works, then try the second just for the experience).